# Should I display my BSc when I have an MSc in a different field?

Tags: canada, title, switzerland, austria

I have a bachelor's degree in aerospace engineering and a master's in forestry (specializing in remote sensing). When applying for jobs, should I write my name as
Lukas Schreiber, BSc, MSc
or as
Lukas Schreiber, MSc
?

What is the common way to do it? And how do people perceive either?

I'm mostly interested in the context of applying for academic or industry jobs in British Columbia, Austria and Switzerland.

EDIT: Note that this is about my name, not my resume. I have both educations listed on my resume.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I list the bachelor's when I have higher degrees?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35379/should-i-list-the-bachelors-when-i-have-higher-degrees)

Comment: You might find this helpful: [What's the proper order for multiple educational degrees/certificates?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/88648)

Comment: The two linked questions are not the same as mine. One is about resumes, and the other is about the ordering of post-nominal letters. I asked what to include in post-nominal letters.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an "Education" section on your resume where you should list both.

As for using either as a suffix for your name...  I wouldn't. In my opinion, it makes you come off as a little pompous. If the job requires a masters degree then adding it to your name is redundant and if it doesn't require a masters degree then you may very well be working alongside people who don't have a masters degree and adding it to your name makes it seem like you're trying to one up them, as it were.

Comment: I suspect you're right for BC because Canadian culture is generally similar to the US.  I'm less confident about Switzerland or Austria though due to the potential for influence from Germany where I know advertising at least some degree types is normal.

Comment: This answer is not really helpful at all since it doesn't address local customs of the countries mentioned. I don't know about British Columbia but Austrians are extremely anal about academic titles, you HAVE to list at least one of them after your name there. For Switzerland you would list neither.

Comment: Correct for Canada, suboptimal for Switzerland and outright WRONG for Austria

Comment: @Peter or Hilmar one of you should create a more complete answer.